# Disable banner ads in WPF WebView control

Tags: .net, wpf, webview, adblock, banner-ads

I use the new WebView control in a WPF application which is based on MS Edge browser. In MS Edge I installed the Adblocker Ultimate extension that blocks annoying banner ads. Obviously this extension is not used in the wpf application. Is there any way to achieve same functionality in the wpf WebView control to disable banner ads or ads in general.

Answer (score 0):

There is a event [UnsafeContentWarningDisplaying](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.win32.ui.controls.wpf.webview.unsafecontentwarningdisplaying?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-stable) which might help you and there are few more events and methods which [help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.win32.ui.controls.wpf.webview?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-stable).

Ultimately you need to write custom code and not allowing those.

Comment: I was afraid that I will get this answer as I do not have enough insight into that particular programming area. But then I give it a try. Thank you.